# How to retrieve a count of keys in a hashtable where the value = $value in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, powershell-5.0

I have a hashtable that stores version numbers of paths to assemblies. I want to find the key of the max value, which I have solved in the function below. I also want to find out if the count of max value is greater than 1 and store that in a variable. Any ideas on how to do the last part?

```
Function Get-LatestDacFxPath
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    $knownPaths = (
        'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120',
        'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130',
        'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140',
        'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin',
        'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin',
        'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin',
        'C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Packages\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild\lib\net40'
    )

    $dacAssembly = 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll'
    [hashtable]$dacVersions = @{}
    foreach($dacPacPath in $knownPaths) 
    {
        if(Test-Path($dacPacPath)) {
            $dacVersions[$dacPacPath] = (Get-ItemProperty -Path (Join-Path $dacPacPath $dacAssembly)).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
        }
    }

    $PathOfLatestVersion = ($dacVersions.GetEnumerator() | sort value -Descending | select -First 1 ).Key
    $LatestVersion = ($dacVersions.GetEnumerator() | sort value -Descending | select -First 1 ).Value
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to figure out whether multiple instances share the highest value, I would use `Group-Object`:

```
$HighestValueBracket = $dacVersions.GetEnumerator() |Group Value |Sort {$_.Name -as [version]} -Descending |Select -First 1
if($HighestValueBracket.Count -gt 1){
    Write-Host "Multiple instances with version $($HighestValueBracket.Name)"
}
```

A simpler, but maybe less intuitive, way of answering this is to sort the values, and test if the two largest values are equal:

```
$sortedVersionEntries = $dacVersions.GetEnumerator() |Sort Value -Descending
if($sortedVersionEntries[0].Value -eq $sortedVersionEntries[1]){
    Write-Host "Multiple instances with version $($sortedVersionEntries[0].Value)"
}
```

---

*I originally misread the question as "how to find hashtable entry with the most items in the value field?"* - if you just want to find the entry with most items, sort on the count of objects in the value field:

```
$HashTable = @{
    a = 1,2
    b = 1
    c = 1,2,3,4
    d = 1,2,3
}
$MaxEntry = $HashTable.GetEnumerator() |Sort {@($_.Value).Count} -Descending |Select -First 1
Write-Host "Key with most entries: $($MaxEntry.Key)"
```

will write "c" to the host

Comment: I'm after a true/false of whether the number of occurrences of max (value)  is greater than 1. Sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: Actually I just solved it with `($dacVersions.GetEnumerator() | where-object {$_.Value -eq $latestVersion}).Count`